# Debugging Web Workers in Safari Web Inspector

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari, web-worker

Chrome's Dev Tools are great for debugging web workers as I can "browse" into that JavaScript environment and set break points. Even the console works as expected.

On Safari, it is a completely different story. `console.log` from the web worker doesn't even print in the console. I see the worker script loaded and I put a break point on it, but it doesn't break. I don't even see the scripts that were loaded with `importScripts`.

How can I use Safari's Web Inspector to troubleshoot problems?

Not that I think it matters, but I'm using Safari 8.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use Safari? Are you investigating a Safari specific problem?

Comment: My company's product supports Safari (and all major browsers) and we want to give customers and support engineers the ability to troubleshoot problems, no matter what web browser.

Comment: Chrome, FireFox, Opera, IE, Edge; All show messages from web workers in the console. Safari? "Ha! we know better, you don't need that.."

Comment: All browser look fine, only Safari has problem, that is why need to debug specifically in Safari.

Comment: @KyawTun read my above comment

Comment: Any solution for this? I need to debug a safari specific worker issue, neither console log, nor debugger working

Comment: I have the same issue, can't set breakpoints in .js files that were loaded in the cache by the service worker...

Answer (score -1):

Insert the `debugger;` code in your source

Usage: Insert it anywhere you want to add a breakpoint and when developer console is open automatically execution will pause at that line

```
var a = 50;
a = a + 5;
debugger; //--> execution is paused here
a = a - 5;
```

For more info see the [Debugger Documentation on mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)

Comment: Do give a descriptive name or title for your links in the future.

Comment: @Daniel A. White , Hi does this work for you?? If yes can you upvote this post??

Comment: Doesn't do anything in Safari (<= 9.1)

Comment: You don't always control all of the source code... I can't use the debugger statement in some instances.... I just don't understand why Apple can't get this right... Works fine in Chrome... but I am stuck in an IOS wrapper project...

Answer (score -3):

In lieu of console.log, you can use postMessage. postMessage should allow you to send debug messages to the safari console.

[Here](http://www.codeovertones.com/2011/08/how-to-debug-webworker-threads.html) is a great example on how to do that, I pasted the main idea below:

```
//
// In the Main thread
//
var worker = new Worker('/path/of/webworker/code.js')
worker.onmessage = function (e) {
  var result = JSON.parse(e.data);
  if(result.type == 'debug') {
    console.log(result.msg);
  } else if(result.type == 'response') {
    // ... use result.answer ...
  }
}


//
// In the WebWorker
//
function debug(msg) {                                                           
  postMessage(JSON.stringify({type:'debug',msg:msg}));                          
}

onmessage = function (e) {
  var inputData = e.data;
  // work on input data
  debug('Working OK');
  // work some more
  // ...
  postMessage(JSON.stringify({type:'response', answer:42}));
};
```

If you don't want to play around with postMessage though, David Flanagan made a wrapper for it [here](https://github.com/davidflanagan/WorkerConsole/) that should allow you to at least do debugging with console.log

Comment: I do know about `postMessage` however i really want to set breakpoints and have a fully debugging experience.